# creating a calculator in c# windows form that can compute multiple operands

Tags: c#

I am making a simple calculator in c# windows form application, it just work fine but my problem is I cannot compute multiple operands,
for example if I add 10 + 10 will result to 20, but if I add 10+10+10 will also result to 20, can someone give me an idea on how can i fix my problem? also how can I prevent user to input many dot(.) characters? I want the user to input only one,, example 2...50 how can I limit it?

Thankyou,

I am sorry,the code posted previuosly was wrong,
This is my new code:

```
namespace Simple_Calculator
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string userInput = string.Empty;
        string operand1 = string.Empty;
        string operand2 = string.Empty;
        double result;

```
    char operation;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 4;
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 0;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 1;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 2;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 3;
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 5;
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 6;
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 7;
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 8;
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 9;
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + '.';
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = textBox1.Text;
        operation = '/';
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = textBox1.Text;
        operation = '*';
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = textBox1.Text;
        operation = '-';
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

    }

    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 =textBox1.Text;
        operation = '+';
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        operand2 = textBox1.Text;
        double num1, num2;
        double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
        double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

        if (operation == '+')
        {
            result = num1 + num2;

            textBox1.Text = result.ToString();

        }
        else if (operation == '-')
        {
            result = num1 - num2;

            textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        }
        else if (operation == '*')
        {

            result = num1 * num2;

            textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        }
        else if (operation == '/')

        {

            result = num1 / num2;

            textBox1.Text = result.ToString();

            if (num2 == 0)

            {
                textBox1.Text = "Cannot be divided by zero";
            }
        }
        else 
        {



        }

        }

    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        userInput = string.Empty;
        operand1 = string.Empty;
        operand2 = string.Empty;
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

This is my GUI, I have not design it yet,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdQ34.png)

Comment: Please show us how `finRes ` is declared. Please also include a screenshot of your UI.

Comment: you need to split the input in tokens and then process them with your math rules. [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs) is a good point to start and then have a look at [NCalc](https://github.com/MichaelAguilar/NCalc), it uses ANTLR to parse string for math calculations.